# Мультиплексированный ввод/вывод в Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, epoll

Есть ли в Windows какой-нибудь аналог мультиплексированного ввода/вывода (epoll/kqueue) из мира Linux? Спрашиваю исходя из того, что выделять буфер на малоактивные сокеты при использовании IOCP не всегда эффективно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) со всеми вытекающими, [WSAPoll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741669(v=vs.85).aspx) или [Event Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms741572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), начиная с Vista.

libev, к примеру, использует select.

WSAPoll задизайнен работать как poll и может использоваться как drop-in-place замена, как-то так:

```
#if defined (WIN32)
static inline int poll( struct pollfd *pfd, int nfds, int timeout) { return WSAPoll ( pfd, nfds, timeout ); }
#endif
```

Event Objects, судя по тем заметкам, что у меня есть, слабо скалируется, может отловить 64 события за раз. Но более подробно не копал.

Интересное чтиво для ознакомления:

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/105918/
- https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/
- https://www.ulduzsoft.com/2014/01/select-poll-epoll-practical-difference-for-system-architects/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpgm-dev/9qA1u-aTIKs